# Python user input split() and loop

Tags: python

I am taking user input as follows: 0,1,2,3,5
The user can write any number and separate it with a comma, the input will be x,y,z,k,c

Then I am having trouble checking if any of the number after split() is invoked is 0 or more than 30.

Code-snippet:

```
numbers = input(user[i]['name'] + 
", assign 10 different numbers between 1-30 (separate each with a comma ','): ")
        usrNums = numbers.split()

for number in usrNums:
    if number < 1 or number > 30: 
     #Something goes here, however, not important now.
```

P.s. I've read a little bit on [all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

**Clarification:** The user inputs some numbers e.g. 0,5,2,9,7,10
the `usrNums = numbers.split()` `split()` is invoked and these are stored in `usrNums`, then I want to check each number in `usrNums [0, 5, 2, 9, 7, 10]` if any of them is "0 meaning number < 1 or > 30".

EDIT: NO THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, I read through, [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python), and it isn't the same at all. My question is about user inputting numbers with separated commas, not one number per input.

Comment: inputs are strings. Keep that in mind ;) Use `eval(number)`in the if statement

Comment: @MMF - Why use `eval` when the right solution is `int`?

Comment: Why are you telling the user to separate their inputs with a comma, and then not splitting the input on a comma?

Comment: not really a duplicate as the question is more about test than input.

Comment: try : any(map(lambda i: i==0 or i>30,numbers)) # test each numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map()` method.

```
numberString = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7'
numbers = map(int, numberString.split(',')) # numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for num in numbers:
    if num < 1 or num > 30:
        # Do whatever you want here...
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

when you use split the numbers are of type string. To compare with 1 or 30 convert these to integers

```
numbers  = "0,1,2,3,5"
usrNums = numbers.split(",")
#usrNums ["0","1","2","3","5"]
for number in usrNums:
    if int(number) < 1 or int(number) > 30:
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,1,2,3,4'

Comment: you fotget the split(",") comma

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = "1,2,3,31"
for number in numbers.split(","):
    number = eval(number) # or use int(number) or float(number) as example
    if number < 1 or number > 30:
        #do something
```

You forget the "," in the split function and forget to convert the string into an integer.

Answer (score -2):

The input is a string. Use `eval` to compare to `int` :

```
for number in usrNums:
     if eval(number) < 1 or eval(number) > 30: 
     #Something goes here, however, not important now.
```

You also need to indicate how to split the string : `input.split(',')`

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()

Comment: `eval`? Really?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thank for the feedback. Can't he use it if he is sure that the user put integers ?

Comment: If you're sure to get integers, why not use `int`? That's what it's for. And if they're not integers, that's even more reason not to use `eval`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ok thanks ;) Then when do you use `eval` instead of `int` ?